# Create new columns by substracting column pairs from each other in R

Tags: r, dplyr, difference

In psychology and related disciplines, we often have a ton of variable name pairs, which are appended e.g. "_T1" or "_T3" to signify time points.

I would like to substract columns with the appendix "_T1" from the ones with appendix "_T3" for each row, creating a new column (i.e. difference score) for every row (i.e. participant), based on each variable pair.

Would prefer a dplyr solution, but anything goes.

Apologies for egregiously breaking any codes of conduct on this first post of mine.

Comment: Try `cbind(df1, df1[grep("_T1", names(df1))] - df1[grep("_T3", names(df1))])` assuming they are in the order

Comment: Please see my answer. Next time, please include a reproducible example of your dataset (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver) and the desired output when asking a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

First, let's create an example data frame. This data frame contains `T1` and `T3` data from two participants `A` and `B`.

```
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create an example data frame
dt <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                 A_T1 = runif(10),
                 A_T3 = runif(10),
                 B_T1 = runif(10),
                 B_T3 = runif(10))
dt
#     ID      A_T1       A_T3      B_T1       B_T3
#  1   1 0.2875775 0.95683335 0.8895393 0.96302423
#  2   2 0.7883051 0.45333416 0.6928034 0.90229905
#  3   3 0.4089769 0.67757064 0.6405068 0.69070528
#  4   4 0.8830174 0.57263340 0.9942698 0.79546742
#  5   5 0.9404673 0.10292468 0.6557058 0.02461368
#  6   6 0.0455565 0.89982497 0.7085305 0.47779597
#  7   7 0.5281055 0.24608773 0.5440660 0.75845954
#  8   8 0.8924190 0.04205953 0.5941420 0.21640794
#  9   9 0.5514350 0.32792072 0.2891597 0.31818101
# 10  10 0.4566147 0.95450365 0.1471136 0.23162579
```

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` to convert the data frame from wide format to long format and perform the operation. `Diff` is the difference between `T1` and `T3`.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -ID) %>%
  separate(Column, into = c("Participant", "Group")) %>%
  spread(Group, Value) %>%
  mutate(Diff = T1 - T3)

dt2
#    ID Participant        T1         T3        Diff
# 1   1           A 0.2875775 0.95683335 -0.66925583
# 2   1           B 0.8895393 0.96302423 -0.07348492
# 3   2           A 0.7883051 0.45333416  0.33497098
# 4   2           B 0.6928034 0.90229905 -0.20949564
# 5   3           A 0.4089769 0.67757064 -0.26859371
# 6   3           B 0.6405068 0.69070528 -0.05019846
# 7   4           A 0.8830174 0.57263340  0.31038400
# 8   4           B 0.9942698 0.79546742  0.19880236
# 9   5           A 0.9404673 0.10292468  0.83754260
# 10  5           B 0.6557058 0.02461368  0.63109211
# 11  6           A 0.0455565 0.89982497 -0.85426847
# 12  6           B 0.7085305 0.47779597  0.23073450
# 13  7           A 0.5281055 0.24608773  0.28201775
# 14  7           B 0.5440660 0.75845954 -0.21439351
# 15  8           A 0.8924190 0.04205953  0.85035951
# 16  8           B 0.5941420 0.21640794  0.37773408
# 17  9           A 0.5514350 0.32792072  0.22351430
# 18  9           B 0.2891597 0.31818101 -0.02902127
# 19 10           A 0.4566147 0.95450365 -0.49788891
# 20 10           B 0.1471136 0.23162579 -0.08451214
```

If the original format is desirable, we can further `spread` the data frame to the original format.

```
dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  select(-starts_with("T")) %>%
  spread(Participant, Diff)

dt3
#    ID          A           B
# 1   1 -0.6692558 -0.07348492
# 2   2  0.3349710 -0.20949564
# 3   3 -0.2685937 -0.05019846
# 4   4  0.3103840  0.19880236
# 5   5  0.8375426  0.63109211
# 6   6 -0.8542685  0.23073450
# 7   7  0.2820178 -0.21439351
# 8   8  0.8503595  0.37773408
# 9   9  0.2235143 -0.02902127
# 10 10 -0.4978889 -0.08451214
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all data are in dataframe `d`, the following will store the variables in columns ending in `_diff`:

```
library(stringr)
t1_vars <- grep("_T1", colnames(d), value=TRUE)
t3_vars <- grep("_T3", colnames(d), value=TRUE)
d[, paste0(str_sub(t1_vars, end=-4), "_diff")] <- d[, t3_vars] - d[, t1_vars]
```